# Complex types and XSDs

Tags: xml, xsd

**Edit: I don't think I asked this question very well.  I'm completely re-phrasing it**

All:
I am trying to represent the following XML in XSD (I'm working with the Visual Studio XSD editor, as I really don't know XSD very well).

```
Here's the XML:

<TheParentNode>
  <AnElement ID="x">123</AnElement>
</TheParentNode>
```

I want to specify that the value of AnElement must be a number.  I also want to put some attributes into AnElement.

What should the XSD look like?

In the Visual Studio designer, I can see how to make AnElement a complex type, and that seems to be the only way to define attributes for it.  However, if I do that, I don't see a way to specify that the value of AnElement must be a number.

Do I need to use complex types?  What would your XSD code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a `complexType` with a `simpleContent`:

```
    <xs:element name="AnElement">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
          <xs:extension base="xs:int">
            <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

That should do the trick. And I'm afraid that's the only way to achieve this. Is it really so bad??

**UPDATE:**
After your update, this is the XSD you'll need:

```
<xs:schema id="TheParentNode" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="TheParentNode">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="AnElement">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:int">
                <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:string" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

You are aware I hope that if you have the XML file open in Visual Studio, you can go to the "XML" menu and pick "Create schema" from it? That does give you a good start usually for your XSD files.

Marc

Comment: Not bad, just trying to figure it out -- I'm pretty new to XSD.

Comment: Thanks again for your updates.  I knew about the xsd support in Visual Studio (and I actually started from a reverse-engineered xsd (generated XSD from xml).  We just need to modify some things that were not captured by the reverse engineering.

Answer (score -1):

How about trying to set up the restriction option with regular express value?  [restriction and pattern xsd tags](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp)

```
 <xs:element name="AnElement">
     <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
 </xs:element>
```

This means it allows only to have integers as zero or more digit.

I hope it helps.

Tiger.

Comment: I wouldn't use something like that, seeing that you already have a xs:int base type in XSD. Why not just define a restriction based on xs:int? Makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Tiger: why go through all that? -1.

Comment: John, I see; but, I was trying to help.  I did not see where was wrong ? I might give wrong direction for that question ? I will appreciate if you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: The xs:int type already restricts the content to digits only. No regular expression facet is necessary.

Comment: I agree with you for the xs:int. I was giving about further extension when I used the pattern tag such as if you want to limit the Five digits for integer, we can express as <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"/>.  anyway, thank you for your comments.

Comment: Four-digit int patterns can be expressed as <xs:restriction base="xs:int"><xs:length value="4"/></xs:restriction> - again: why use xs:string and regular expressions and make things more complicated than they need to be?

Comment: That is true. I changed the xs:string. Thank you for your comments.